# subscription on template with async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I've stuck with an issue when I'm trying to use `async` pipe on my template:

template portion is:

```
<div [innerHTML]="(user$ | async).cname"></div>
```

component is trying to create an `Observable<IUser>` on `user$` field:

```
this.user$ = this.store$
  .select(fromRoot.getUserState)
  .filter((user: IUser) => user.id != null)
  .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$);
```

This `Observable` reacts according to `dispatch` action on `do(...)`:

```
this.route.queryParams
  .map(params => ({id: params['id'] || undefined, token: params['token'] || undefined}))
  .filter(params => params.id != undefined && params.token != undefined)
  .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
  .do(params => this.store$.dispatch({type: 'LOAD_USER', payload: {b64: params.id}}))
  .subscribe();
```

Nevertheless, I don't quite to achieve the received `user.cname` is shown on rendered html.

I've tried to print it out on console, and it's really printed correctly:

```
this.store$
  .select(fromRoot.getUserState)
  .filter((user: IUser) => user.id != null)
  .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
  .do((user: IUser) => console.warn(user.cname))
  .subscribe();
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've added a `do` operator on obversable in order to print out `user.cname`.

```
this.user$ = this.store$
  .select(fromRoot.getUserState)
  .filter((user: IUser) => user.id != null)
  .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
  .do((user: IUser) => console.warn(user.cname));
```

`user.cname` is always printed out on console, nevertheless, **sometimes** is rendered on html.

Comment: `<div [innerHTML]="(user$ | async).cname"></div>` and you try to console.warn : `console.warn(user.name)`. cname VS name, typo ?

Comment: Sorry @Maxime. It just was a miswritting. I've realized that when the component is loaded `cname` is not shown. Nevertheless, when I'm debugging, it's shown instead. I'm also realizing `.filter((user: IUser) => user.id != null)` lambda should be reached twice. I mean, the first one, when it's subscribed (receive current user state) and then after having dispatched `LOAD_USER -> LOAD_USER_SUCCESS (this recuder changes user state`), but it's only reached once. Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited the post. `user.cname` is alwats printed out on console, nevertheless, sometimes it's rendered on html...

Comment: Sorry @Maxime. I've just realized that I'm getting this error message: `Error: Error in ./Validate class Validate - inline template:13:15 caused by: valUnwrapper.unwrap(...) is null`. Does it mean `user$` observable is null when template is getting rendered?